# How to update access database that is connected to my Visual Basic project on Visual Studio

Tags: vba, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

I managed to connect my database to Visual studio successfully and all the tables and the fields in the database appeared in Visual studio. I added a new field to one of the tables and removed a table entirely from the database yet the newly added field won't show up on Visual studio and the deleted table still appears on Visual Studio as if nothing changed. What do?

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting and reconnecting in the Server Explorer, then refresh the App_Data folder.